# "Unconstrained generic constant" when adding const generics

Tags: rust

How would I add const generics? Lets say I have a type foo:

```
pub struct foo <const bar: i64> {
    value: f64,
}
```

and I want to implement mul so I can multiply 2 `foo`s together. I want to treat `bar` as a dimension, so `foo<baz>{value: x} * foo<quux>{value: k} == foo<baz + quux>{value: x * k}`, as follows:

```
impl<const baz: i64, const quux: i64> Mul<foo<quux>> for foo<baz> {
    type Output = foo<{baz + quux}>;

    fn mul(self, rhs: foo<quux>) -> Self::Output {
        Self::Output {
            value: self.value * rhs.value,
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error telling me I need to add a where bound on `{baz+quux}` within the definition of the output type. What exactly does this mean and how do I implement it? I can't find any seemingly relevant information on `where`.

Comment: Const generics are very unstable and I feel that this is one of the many issues that they're trying to fix.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## The solution

I got a variation on your code to work [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a5bcf2e29cd50a11f6d2ff2bea498b64):

```rust
impl<const baz: i64, const quux: i64> Mul<Foo<quux>> for Foo<baz>
    where Foo<{baz + quux}>: Sized {
    type Output = Foo<{baz + quux}>;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Foo<quux>) -> Self::Output {
        Self::Output {
            value: self.value * rhs.value,
        }
    }
}
```

## How I got there

I've reproduced the full error that you get without the added `where` clause below:

```
error: unconstrained generic constant
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     type Output = Foo<{baz + quux}>;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
help: try adding a `where` bound using this expression: `where [u8; {baz + quux}]: Sized`
```

Now, the clause that it suggests is not very useful, for one reason: the length parameter of a statically sized slice must be a `usize`, but our values `baz` and `quux` (and their sum) are `i64`. I'd imagine that the compiler authors included that particular suggestion because the primary use case for const generics is embedding array sizes in types. I've [opened an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/82509) about this diagnostic.

## Why is this necessary?

A `where` clause specifies constraints on some generic code element---a function, type, trait, or in this case, implementation---based on the traits and lifetimes that one or more generic parameters, or a derivative thereof, must satisfy. There are equivalent shorthands for many cases, but the overall requirement is that the constraints are fully specified.

In our case, it may seem superficially that this implementation works for any combination of `baz` and `quux`, but this is not the case, due to integer overflow; if we supply sufficiently large values of the same sign for both, their sum cannot be represented by `i64`. This means that `i64` is not closed under addition.

The constraint that we add requires that the sum of the two values is in the set of possible values of an `i64`, indirectly, by requiring something of the type which consumes it. Hence, supplying 2^31 for both `baz` and `quux` is not valid, since the resulting type `Foo<{baz + quux}>` does not exist, so it cannot possibly implement the `Sized` trait. While this technically is a stricter constraint than we need (`Sized` is a stronger requirement than a type simply existing), all `Foo<bar>` which exist implement `Sized`, so in our case it is the same. On the other hand, without the constraint, no `where` clause, explicit or shorthand, specifies this constraint.

Comment: Thank you as well for the 'How I got here/Why is this necessary', that was insightful.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. That's some weird edge case one could encounter.

Comment: I can't think of any situation where "`Sized` is a stronger requirement than a type simply existing", but in that case that ever happens, we can do something like: `trait Exists {}` `impl<T: ?Sized> Exists for T {}`.

Comment: @RoyCohen unsized types exist, primarily trait objects, slices, and in some cases types built from them. And in latest Rust you can actually do `where Foo<{baz + quux}>:`, i.e., you can have an empty list of trait bounds.