# Why is an empty where constraint needed for a generic constant expression?

Tags: rust, syntax, const-generics

I would like to define a struct like this, but the compiler yields an error:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

struct ArInt<const W: usize, const S: bool> {
    iarr: [i32; { (W + 31 + (!S) as usize) / 32 }],
}
```

```
error: unconstrained generic constant
 --> src/lib.rs:4:11
  |
4 |     iarr: [i32; { (W + 31 + (!S) as usize) / 32 }],
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = help: try adding a `where` bound using this expression: `where [(); { (W + 31 + (!S) as usize) / 32 }]:`
```

I made the following modification as per the compiler's suggestion and it works:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

struct ArInt<const W: usize, const S: bool>
where
    [(); { (W + 31 + (!S) as usize) / 32 }]:
{
    iarr: [i32; { (W + 31 + (!S) as usize) / 32 }],
}
```

Can someone explain the `where` clause's constraint meaning here? It looks weird.

Comment: Well, this is a [weird](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7433b5149c13d2efa572be5bbce3fb33) one. Also possibly a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66361365/unconstrained-generic-constant-when-adding-const-generics).

Comment: @Caesar You don't even need `Sized`. You can just leave it blank.

Comment: Wat. I thought that was just the rustc recommendations being broken… So yeah, @YanZhu, there you have it: The solution to your problem is written in your question.

Comment: [Doesn't have to be](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cfd4512e5f80978f02a62f9d1972d29a) an `[i32;…]` either. Weird stuff that.

Comment: @Caesar Somehow you are right. But it looks weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context `where [(); {(W + 31 + (!S) as usize)/32}]:` means more or less: "*where `[(); {(W + 31 + (!S) as usize)/32}]` is a possible type*". This makes the allowed values clear from the get go. For example you can't do this:

```
let f: ArInt<usize::MAX, true>;
```

because `usize::MAX + 31` would overflow. The `where` clause makes that constraint visible without you needing to go through the implementation details to see it.