# Is it possible to define a function recursively on const generic in rust?

Tags: rust

Here is an example, to implement a function to compute the NxN matrix's determinant recursively. Following is my "best" try so far

```rust
pub type Matrix<const M: usize, const N: usize> = [[f64; N]; M];

pub trait Determinant {
    fn determinant(&self) -> f64;
}

impl<const N: usize> Determinant for Matrix<N, N>
where [(); N-1]:,
      [(); N-1-1]:
{
    fn determinant(&self) -> f64 {
        ...
    }
}

impl Determinant for Matrix<2,2> {
    fn determinant(&self) -> f64 {
        self[0][0] * self[1][1] - self[0][1]*self[1][0]
    }
}
```

Here, I try to use `where [(); N-1-1]` to bind the first implementation to condition `N > 2`. But the compiler still complains about conflict implementation.

I am wondering if it is possible to achieve such things in rust.

Comment: `[(); N-2]` is compatible with `N=2`. `[(); 0]` is a valid type.

Comment: @jthulhu Thanks for the comment. I try with "[();  N-3]" or "[(); N-1-1-1]" and I got error "112 |       [(); {N-1-1-1}]:
    |             ^^^^^^^ attempt to compute `0_usize - 1_usize`, which would overflow"

Comment: I think this is because, currently, this kind of constraint is not understood symbolically. It will just try to evaluate it and, if it fails, it gives an error. This can be used to prevent a certain implementation to be used, but not to make the compiler understand that that implementation is only valid for certain values of `N`. AFAIK this is a WIP feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is not capable of making the reasoning you want it to. The `where` clause restricts the impl from being used, but does not prevent it from conflicting. However, if you feel confident using the very unstable `generic_const_exprs`, maybe you will feel OK using specialization too?

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs, min_specialization)]

pub type Matrix<const M: usize, const N: usize> = [[f64; N]; M];

pub trait Determinant {
    fn determinant(&self) -> f64;
}

impl<const N: usize> Determinant for Matrix<N, N>
where [(); N-1]:,
      [(); N-1-1]:
{
    default fn determinant(&self) -> f64 {
        ...
    }
}

impl Determinant for Matrix<2, 2> {
    fn determinant(&self) -> f64 {
        self[0][0] * self[1][1] - self[0][1]*self[1][0]
    }
}
```

Comment: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8bfd3d8368404121d15a9929f522f991) It works. I think "min_specialization" is also necessary

Comment: @YanZhu I included it in my answer.

Comment: I mean I only had "generic_const_exprs" before and got the original error message.

Answer (score 1):

### Recursively returning `Self::<{DEPTH + 1}>`

I had a similar problem for recursively returning `self` when working with tree graphs.

I was only able to get it working with the `<Out>` constrait, inspired by how `std::ops::Mul` works, as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66362584/2556034). The solution also catches overflows at compile time:

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]
#![allow(incomplete_features)]

struct Node<const DEPTH: usize>;

impl<const DEPTH: usize> Node<DEPTH> {
    pub fn get_depth(&self) -> usize { DEPTH }
}

trait IntoChild<Out> {
    fn into_child(self) -> Out;
}

impl<const DEPTH: usize> IntoChild<Node<{ DEPTH + 1 }>> for Node<DEPTH> {
    fn into_child(self) -> Node<{ DEPTH + 1 }> { Node::<{ DEPTH + 1 }> }
}

fn main() {
    let parent = Node::<0>;
    let child = parent.into_child();
    assert_eq!(child.get_depth(), 1);

    const MAX_USIZE: usize = usize::MAX;
    let parent = Node::<MAX_USIZE>;
    // ERROR: attempt to compute `usize::MAX + 1_usize`, which would overflow
    let child = parent.into_child();
}
```